# How to pass variable from WidgetBase to .module

Tags: 8, hooks

In Drupal 8 my module looks like this.

```
<?php

function signature_field_theme() {

  $theme = [];
  $theme['signature'] = [
    'render element' => 'element',
    'variables' => array(
      'sign_src' => NULL,
      'text_area_id' => NULL,
      ),
  ];
  return $theme;
}

function signature_field_page_attachments_alter(&$page) {
  $page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['signature_field']['sign']['id'] = 'id';
}
```

My SignatureWidget.php file looks like this...

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\signature_field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
use Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManagerInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'field_signature_field_widget' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "field_signature_field_widget",
 *   module = "signature_field",
 *   label = @Translation("Signature Data"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "field_signature"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class SignatureWidget extends WidgetBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $value = isset($items[$delta]->value) ? $items[$delta]->value : '';

     // 
     //$sign_thumb = array( '#type'   => 'html_tag',
     //                     '#tag' => 'img',
     //                     '#attributes' => array('src' => '', 'id' => 'signature_thumb_test', 'class'=>array('align-right'), 'width' =>'120px', 'height' => '60px' ));

    $field_name = $items->getName();

    /*function getFieldName() {
      return $field_name;
    }*/

    $text_area_id = 'signature_field_' . $field_name;  

    $file_upload_help = array(
      '#theme' => 'signature',
      '#sign_src' => $value,
      '#text_area_id' => $text_area_id,
    );

    $element += array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#default_value' => $value,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => array($text_area_id),
                        ),
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' => array('signature_field/signature_pad'),
                        ),
    );
    $element['#attached']['library'][] = 'signature_field/signature_pad';
    $element['#description'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($file_upload_help);
    //$element['#suffix'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($sign_thumb);

    return array('value' => $element);
  }

}
```

How can I pass $text_area_id from the widget to the module in order to use it as a variable in `function signature_field_page_attachments_alter`

Comment: No offense, but this doesn't make sense. The alter hook is intended to extend libraries, if original methods don't provide all you need. But in this case you built the widget yourself. Why don't you attach the settings in your form element, right after you attach your library?

Comment: Yes, you you can add drupalSettings anywhere you have a render array, just put it directly in your widget and you're done.

Comment: The previous explanation at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module#configurable was somewhat misleading and could suggest passing `drupalSettings` to JavaScript is possible in `hook_page_attachments_alter()` only. I just updated the docs accordingly.

Comment: Thank you both. Thats exactly what I needed. I don't know why I didn't think to try it in my existing form element. Sorry I'm still trying to understand how the D8 module file structure works and what I can do where. Is there anywhere you'd recommend learning more about this? Every example as you had mentioned Mario appeared to call it in one of the hooks. Thanks for updating the docs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase someone stumbles upon this and struggles to follow the thread above this is how to pass the variable.

```
$element['#attached']['drupalSettings']['signature_field']['sign']['id'] = $text_area_id;
```

Here is the full widget code.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\signature_field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
use Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManagerInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'field_signature_field_widget' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "field_signature_field_widget",
 *   module = "signature_field",
 *   label = @Translation("Signature Data"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "field_signature"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class SignatureWidget extends WidgetBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $value = isset($items[$delta]->value) ? $items[$delta]->value : '';

     // 
     //$sign_thumb = array( '#type'   => 'html_tag',
     //                     '#tag' => 'img',
     //                     '#attributes' => array('src' => '', 'id' => 'signature_thumb_test', 'class'=>array('align-right'), 'width' =>'120px', 'height' => '60px' ));

    $field_name = $items->getName();

    /*function getFieldName() {
      return $field_name;
    }*/

    $text_area_id = 'signature_field_' . $field_name;  

    $file_upload_help = array(
      '#theme' => 'signature',
      '#sign_src' => $value,
      '#text_area_id' => $text_area_id,
    );

    $element += array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#default_value' => $value,  
      '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => array($text_area_id),
                        ),
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' => array('signature_field/signature_pad'),
                        ),
    );
    $element['#attached']['library'][] = 'signature_field/signature_pad';
    $element['#description'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($file_upload_help);
    $element['#attached']['drupalSettings']['signature_field']['sign']['id'] = $text_area_id;

    return array('value' => $element);
  }

}
```

It is then available in your JS as follows.

```
var canvasId = drupalSettings.signature_field.sign.id;
            console.log(canvasId);
```